# How to use & selector in Sass version 3.4.22?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following piece of code in my .scss file:

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 30px;
    &-nav{
        li{
            a {
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is generating the following error:

Syntax error: Invalid CSS after " &:" expected "{", was "-nav{"

Basically, I want my resulting selector to be .navbar-nav, can anyone let me know how to implement this in Sass 3.4.22

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets and semicolons and use indentation:

```
.navbar 
  min-height: 30px
  &-nav
    li
      a 
        padding-top: 5px
        padding-bottom: 5px
```

From RubyDoc:

> Sass has two syntaxes. The new main syntax (as of Sass 3) is known as
>   "SCSS" (for "Sassy CSS"), and is a superset of CSS's syntax. This
>   means that every valid CSS stylesheet is valid SCSS as well. SCSS
>   files use the extension .scss.
>
> The second, older syntax is known as the indented syntax (or just
>   "Sass"). Inspired by Haml's terseness, it's intended for people who
>   prefer conciseness over similarity to CSS. Instead of brackets and
>   semicolons, it uses the indentation of lines to specify blocks.
>   Although no longer the primary syntax, the indented syntax will
>   continue to be supported. Files in the indented syntax use the
>   extension .sass.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your example to http://www.sassmeister.com/ it works as expected. They're using `v3.4.21`.

Maybe try wrapping the `&` symbol with interpolation helpers `#{&}`:

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 30px;
    #{&}-nav { 
        li{
            a {
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should produce the same result.